# Automate clicking for disabled button

Tags: button, click

I am trying to automate button click to "www.truecaller.com" , but there are 2 issues :
 - I can not get the button ID.
 - seems that this button is always disabled. if I enter data manually to the phone number textbox , it is enabled. But if I filled data to this textbox automatically from my application , it will always stay disabled.

Thanks for support.

Walid

Comment: What library are you using to fill in fields and click buttons?

Comment: I am using vb.net , and use the webbrowser

Comment: code is :  wb.Document.GetElementById("phone_number").InnerText = "0111118"

Comment: You might want to add a VB tag to this question to get more people to look at it -- sorry I don't use VB so don't know the API for the webbrowser control but you either need to generate key events to trigger the validation and enabling of the button or you need to manually enable the button by removing the disabled attribute.   Of course you could also just submit a POST yourself that mimics what the form is doing.

Comment: no problem. Thanks any way for your interest